# What's the limit of $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}-e^{-x}+x^2+x$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find a good way to calculate this limit :

$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}-e^{-x}+x^2+x$

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? This is a test of basic understanding of common functions and I suggest you at least try to sketch the function before asking questions about it.

Comment: @MarkBennet We are asked to draw the graph of the function in exams (Handy), so we have to calculate the limit before because it help us figure out the behavior of the curve.

Comment: If you don't know the behaviour of the curve do something like calculating values at $x=-1, x=-10$ - you should be able to sketch $x+x^2$ very easily and then $-e^{-x}$ is a question of negotiating those minus signs correctly - it will be negative because $e^{anything real}$ is positive - and it will either be growing in magnitude faster than any polynomial (remember the series expansion of $e^x$), or subsiding towards zero so that the polynomial part dominates. You just have to work out which.

Comment: no, I mean we have to calculate the limit to sketch the curve.

Comment: And I have shown some ways of sketching the curve/finding the limit in my second comment - like punching actual values into your calculator, or finding a way to estimate what is going on. As soon as you get a good estimate it will be obvious what you need to do. I also mentioned the key property of the exponential function for questions like this in my second comment. When you understand the functions you will find problems like this obvious - so work on understanding basic rates of growth - exponential v polynomial is basic.

Answer (score 6):

An idea:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}-e^{-x}+x^2+x=\lim_{x\to-\infty}-\frac{1-x^2e^x-xe^x}{e^x}=-\frac{1-0-0}{0^+} \text{ (symbolic)}=-\infty$$

Comment: How did you know that it is a positive $0$ there in the denominator ?

Comment: Exponential functions for real numbers can _only_ give positive values.